# Background isolate platform channel difference between internal and external plugins

Tags: android, flutter, dart-isolates

I have a background isolate trying to use a platform channel. Yes, Flutter 3.7+, channels set up according to the background isolate requirements (including calling `BackgroundIsolateBinaryMessenger.ensureInitialized()`). From the isolate, I can successfully call *outside* plugins communicating through their channels, everything works beautifully. The problem is when calling my own plugin *inside* the same project. And I cannot identify what's handled differently in the framework depending on where the plugin is located.

Being an internal plugin, the toolchain doesn't pick it up and doesn't add it to `GeneratedPluginRegistrant`, so I do it manually in my `FlutterActivity`:

```
override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
  flutterEngine.plugins.add(MainPlugin())
  super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
}
```

My plugin is a standard `FlutterPlugin`, also `ActivityAware` and `MethodCallHandler`. I tried to set up the channel both in the simpler form and on the task queue as the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels#using-plugins-and-channels-from-background-isolates) recommends:

```
override fun onAttachedToEngine(binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
  val taskQueue = binding.binaryMessenger.makeBackgroundTaskQueue()
  channel = MethodChannel(binding.binaryMessenger, "com.example.foreground_test/platform", StandardMethodCodec.INSTANCE, taskQueue)
  //channel = MethodChannel(binding.binaryMessenger, "com.example.foreground_test/platform")
  channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
}
```

The plugin works from the main isolate all right, just not from the background one. The latter results in the usual *MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method test on channel com.example.foreground_test/platform)* error.

What might be set up differently by the framework when the plugin is inside? Why does it matter at all in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation, with input from the core Flutter developers, the cause was identified. The code created a secondary FlutterEngine and while outside plugins were automatically associated with both, my own internal code was only registered to the main engine manually, not to the secondary one.